# Inserting ampersand into SQL table through PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, insert, sql-injection

I'm currently able to insert data into a SQL DB using the .php below however if the data contains an ampersand it treats it as a PHP statement and the ampersand doesn't get inserted into the DB.

For example, the data I entered into the work_carried_out field was:

> Archived from 25th June all spl and inp from
>   c:\versionone\dbcheck_1000\inbound_1000\DESPATCH\ &
>   c:\versionone\dbcheck_1000\inbound_1000\DESPATCH\done to c:\Despatch
>   Archive

and this is what was written to the table:

> Archived from 25th June all spl and inp from
>   c:\versionone\dbcheck_1000\inbound_1000\DESPATCH\

**Database schema**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[server_log_entries](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [start_date_time] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [finish_date_time] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [server_name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [carried_out_by] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [verified_by] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [authorised_by] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [work_carried_out] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [work_verified] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [change_reason] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [perceived_impact] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [rollback_process] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_server_log_entries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Code**

```
// Get the form fields and remove whitespace
var_dump($_POST);

$datetime = trim($_POST["datetime"]);
$servername = trim($_POST["servername"]);
$carriedoutby = trim($_POST["carriedoutby"]);
$workverifiedby = trim($_POST["workverifiedby"]);
$authorisedby = trim($_POST["authorisedby"]);
$workcarriedout = trim($_POST["workcarriedout"]);
$howverified = trim($_POST["howverified"]);
$reason = trim($_POST["reason"]);
$impact = trim($_POST["impact"]);
$rollback = trim($_POST["rollback"]);


try {
    $db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


// Insert data into SQL table
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO [dbo].[server_log_entries] (date_time, server_name, carried_out_by, verified_by, authorised_by, work_carried_out, work_verified, change_reason, perceived_impact, rollback_process)
                 values (:datetime,:servername,:carriedoutby,:workverifiedby,:authorisedby,:workcarriedout,:howverified,:reason,:impact,:rollback)");

$stmt->bindParam(':datetime', $datetime, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':servername', $servername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':carriedoutby', $carriedoutby, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':workverifiedby', $workverifiedby, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':authorisedby', $authorisedby, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':workcarriedout', $workcarriedout, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':howverified', $howverified, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':reason', $reason, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':impact', $impact, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':rollback', $rollback, PDO::PARAM_STR);


$stmt->execute();

$db = null;
```

Comment: *"however if the data contains an ampersand it treats it as a PHP statement"* - for which POST array(s) / column(s) is that? You need to edit  your post to include it for future users, since some of us may not still be present in the question, waiting for a response. The schema for it also.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- it was the workcarriedout column in this instance, the info I entered in was "Archived from 25th June all spl and inp from c:\versionone\dbcheck_1000\inbound_1000\DESPATCH\ & c:\versionone\dbcheck_1000\inbound_1000\DESPATCH\done to c:\Despatch Archive" and this is what was written to the table: "Archived from 25th June all spl and inp from c:\versionone\dbcheck_1000\inbound_1000\DESPATCH\"

Comment: Can you show us the schema for the table as well? Data type/length etc...

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is on this end and not in the code that sends the data? Does your `var_dump($_POST)` contain the correct data? Does it come from a form, service, app?

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson - I've added this example to the original post for you

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this is through a webpage I've created, it sends the data from the field directly to the .php code that I have mentioned in the example, all other data goes into the table fine

Comment: So it's a form? And how about the `var_dump()`, does it contain the correct data? You need to walk us through what you have debugged and what the results were.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hello. Have you found your solution? Can I be of any further assistance?

Comment: Hi @aendeerei, thank you for your help - I'm using Microsoft SQL Server not MySQL (I should have mentioned that sorry)

Comment: You are welcome. No problem, I thought so already. But have you tried my solution? It should apply to SQL Server as well. I'm just interested in finding out if changing double quotes to single quotes in sql statement made a difference. Actually I'm very curious about this strange parsing-behaviour of PHP engine :-) The other answer part is just optional for you.

Comment: @aendeerei I did try the single quotes but that didn't make a difference unfortunately :( - I'm currently putting the code you've provided in place and I'll let you know the result. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Oh :-( I'm sorry it didn't work out. For me and others that made the magic. With pleasure. Good luck and ask if you have any questions. P.S: Look for escaping possibilities in SQL Server and make sure that all charset encodings on your db AND web server are uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I use MySQL as RDBMS.

As strange as it may seem, the problem is - I hope to be in your case, too - that the SQL statement is delimited by double quotes ("). Replace them with single quotes ('). Also, consider to apply `PDO::quote` if you are having problems with the backslashes.

Please note that the PDO exceptions are emitted not only on connection creation, but also by other PDO functions like `PDO::prepare`. In general it's good to check the documentation of each function, in order to find out which values AND/or exceptions are returned/thrown.

I made a complete code, which I post here; maybe you find something useful from the exception/returned values handling point of view. You should just change the DSN and the credentials to fit your system. As a personal choice I used `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`.

Good luck!

---

### PDO prepared statements + exception handling:

#### index.php (main page)

```
<?php

require_once 'configs.php';
require_once 'functions.php';
require_once 'testFunctions.php';

// Activate error reporting (only on development).
activateErrorReporting();

// Get the form fields and remove whitespace
$datetime = trim($_POST["datetime"]);
$servername = trim($_POST["servername"]);
$carriedoutby = trim($_POST["carriedoutby"]);
$workverifiedby = trim($_POST["workverifiedby"]);
$authorisedby = trim($_POST["authorisedby"]);
$workcarriedout = trim($_POST["workcarriedout"]);
$howverified = trim($_POST["howverified"]);
$reason = trim($_POST["reason"]);
$impact = trim($_POST["impact"]);
$rollback = trim($_POST["rollback"]);

try {
    // Create db connection.
    $connection = createConnection(
            MYSQL_HOST
            , MYSQL_DATABASE
            , MYSQL_USERNAME
            , MYSQL_PASSWORD
            , MYSQL_PORT
            , MYSQL_CHARSET
    );

    // Insert data.
    $lastInsertId = insertData(
            $connection
            , $datetime
            , $servername
            , $carriedoutby
            , $workverifiedby
            , $authorisedby
            , $workcarriedout
            , $howverified
            , $reason
            , $impact
            , $rollback
    );

    // Print data (for testing purposes).
    printData($lastInsertId, TRUE);

    // Fetch all data.
    $fetchedLastInsertedData = fetchData($connection, $lastInsertId);

    // For testing purposes.
    printData($fetchedLastInsertedData, TRUE);

    closeConnection($connection);
} catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
    // On development.
    printData($pdoException, TRUE);

    // On production.
    // echo $pdoException->getMessage();

    exit();
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    // On development.
    printData($exception, TRUE);

    // On production.
    // echo $exception->getMessage();

    exit();
}
```

#### testFunctions.php

```
<?php

/*
 * ---------------------
 * Test functions
 * ---------------------
 */

/**
 * Insert data.
 * 
 * @param PDO $connection Connection instance.
 * @param type $datetime
 * @param type $servername
 * @param type $carriedoutby
 * @param type $workverifiedby
 * @param type $authorisedby
 * @param type $workcarriedout
 * @param type $howverified
 * @param type $reason
 * @param type $impact
 * @param type $rollback
 * @return integer Last insert id.
 * @throws Exception
 */
function insertData(
        $connection
        , $datetime
        , $servername
        , $carriedoutby
        , $workverifiedby
        , $authorisedby
        , $workcarriedout
        , $howverified
        , $reason
        , $impact
        , $rollback
) {
    // Sql statement.
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[server_log_entries] (
                date_time,
                server_name,
                carried_out_by,
                verified_by,
                authorised_by,
                work_carried_out,
                work_verified,
                change_reason,
                perceived_impact,
                rollback_process
            ) VALUES (
                :datetime,
                :servername,
                :carriedoutby,
                :workverifiedby,
                :authorisedby,
                :workcarriedout,
                :howverified,
                :reason,
                :impact,
                :rollback
            )';

    // Prepare and check sql statement (returns PDO statement).
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    if (!$statement) {
        throw new Exception('The SQL statement can not be prepared!');
    }

    // Bind values to sql statement parameters.
    $statement->bindValue(':datetime', $datetime, getInputParameterDataType($datetime));
    $statement->bindValue(':servername', $servername, getInputParameterDataType($servername));
    $statement->bindValue(':carriedoutby', $carriedoutby, getInputParameterDataType($carriedoutby));
    $statement->bindValue(':workverifiedby', $workverifiedby, getInputParameterDataType($workverifiedby));
    $statement->bindValue(':authorisedby', $authorisedby, getInputParameterDataType($authorisedby));
    $statement->bindValue(':workcarriedout', $workcarriedout, getInputParameterDataType($workcarriedout));
    $statement->bindValue(':howverified', $howverified, getInputParameterDataType($howverified));
    $statement->bindValue(':reason', $reason, getInputParameterDataType($reason));
    $statement->bindValue(':impact', $impact, getInputParameterDataType($impact));
    $statement->bindValue(':rollback', $rollback, getInputParameterDataType($rollback));

    // Execute and check PDO statement.
    if (!$statement->execute()) {
        throw new Exception('The PDO statement can not be executed!');
    }

    // Get last insert id.
    return $connection->lastInsertId();
}

/**
 * Fetch data by id.
 * 
 * @param PDO $connection Connection instance.
 * @param integer $id Record id.
 * @return array Fetched data.
 * @throws Exception
 */
function fetchData($connection, $id) {
    // Sql statement.
    $sql = 'SELECT * 
            FROM [dbo].[server_log_entries]
            WHERE id = :id';

    // Prepare and check sql statement (returns PDO statement).
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    if (!$statement) {
        throw new Exception('The SQL statement can not be prepared!');
    }

    // Bind values to sql statement parameters.
    $statement->bindValue(':id', $id, getInputParameterDataType($id));

    // Execute and check PDO statement.
    if (!$statement->execute()) {
        throw new Exception('The PDO statement can not be executed!');
    }

    // Fetch data.
    $fetchedData = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($fetchedData === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception('Fetching data failed!');
    }

    return $fetchedData;
}
```

#### configs.php

```
<?php

/*
 * ----------------
 * Database configs
 * ----------------
 */

define('MYSQL_HOST', '...');
define('MYSQL_PORT', '3306');
define('MYSQL_DATABASE', '...');
define('MYSQL_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('MYSQL_USERNAME', '...');
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', '...');
```

#### functions.php

```
<?php

/*
 * ---------------------
 * Data access functions
 * ---------------------
 */

/**
 * Create a new db connection.
 * 
 * @param string $host Host.
 * @param string $dbname Database name.
 * @param string $username Username.
 * @param string $password Password.
 * @param string $port [optional] Port.
 * @param array $charset [optional] Character set.
 * @param array $options [optional] Driver options.
 * @return PDO Db connection.
 */
function createConnection($host, $dbname, $username, $password, $port = '3306', $charset = 'utf8', $options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
)) {
    $dsn = getDsn($host, $dbname, $port, $charset);
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        $connection->setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
    return $connection;
}

/**
 * Create a mysql DSN string.
 * 
 * @param string $host Host.
 * @param string $dbname Database name.
 * @param string $port [optional] Port.
 * @param array $charset [optional] Character set.
 * @return string DSN string.
 */
function getDsn($host, $dbname, $port = '3306', $charset = 'utf8') {
    $dsn = sprintf('mysql:host=%s;port=%s;dbname=%s;charset=%s'
            , $host
            , $port
            , $dbname
            , $charset
    );
    return $dsn;
}

/**
 * Close a db connection.
 * 
 * @param PDO $connection Db connection.
 * @return void
 */
function closeConnection($connection) {
    $connection = NULL;
}

/**
 * Get the data type of a binding value.
 * 
 * @param mixed $value Binding value.
 * @return mixed Data type of the binding value.
 */
function getInputParameterDataType($value) {
    $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    if (is_int($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
    } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    }
    return $dataType;
}

/*
 * ---------------
 * Print functions
 * ---------------
 */

/**
 * Print data on screen.
 * 
 * @param mixed $data Data to print.
 * @param bool $preformatted Print preformatted if TRUE, print normal otherwise.
 * @return void
 */
function printData($data, $preformatted = FALSE) {
    if ($preformatted) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';
    } else {
        echo $data;
    }
}

/*
 * -------------------------
 * Error reporting functions
 * -------------------------
 */

/**
 * Toggle error reporting.
 * 
 * @param integer $level Error level.
 * @param bool $displayErrors Display errors if TRUE, hide them otherwise.
 * @return void
 */
function activateErrorReporting($level = E_ALL, $displayErrors = TRUE) {
    error_reporting($level);
    ini_set('display_errors', ($displayErrors ? 1 : 0));
}
```

Comment: For the users who downvote(d) my question: Please let me know the motives of your downvote, so that I can change my answer correspondingly. This way we can contribute together to the continuous improvement of this website. Thank you.